# Get order items inside the order

Tags: magento-1.9, orders

I need to get order item inside the order loop , how to achieve this, 
here is my code

```
      $orderCollection = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection();





    foreach ($orderCollection as $order) {
        $orders['orders'][] = array(
            'id'            => $order->getIncrementId(),
            'store'         => 'magento',
            'status'        => $order->getStatus(),
            'name'          => $order->getCustomerName(),
            'email'         => $order->getCustomerEmail(),
            'telephone'     => $order->getShippingAddress()->getTelephone(),
            'street'        => $order->getShippingAddress()->getStreet(),
            'pincode'       => $order->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode(),
            'city'          => $order->getShippingAddress()->getCity(),
            'weight'        => $order->getWeight(),


        );




     foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $orders['items'][] = array(
            'id'            => $order->getIncrementId(),
            'name'          => $item->getName(),
            'sku'           => $item->getSku(),
            'Price'         => $item->getPrice(),
            'Ordered Qty'   => $item->getQtyOrdered(),


        );

     }

    }
    return $orders;
}
```

I need to combine these two in a single array with order and order item displayed in the same array.

Comment: how to iterate through foreach loop if i have 2 datas for order

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/143592)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/143592)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try below code:

```
foreach ($orderCollection as $order) {
  $items=array();
  foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $items[] = array(
            'id'            => $order->getIncrementId(),
            'name'          => $item->getName(),
            'sku'           => $item->getSku(),
            'Price'         => $item->getPrice(),
            'Ordered Qty'   => $item->getQtyOrdered(),
        );
    }
    $orders['orders'][] = array(
        'id'            => $order->getIncrementId(),
        'store'         => 'magento',
        'status'        => $order->getStatus(),
        'name'          => $order->getCustomerName(),
        'email'         => $order->getCustomerEmail(),
        'telephone'     => $order->getShippingAddress()->getTelephone(),
        'street'        => $order->getShippingAddress()->getStreet(),
        'pincode'       => $order->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode(),
        'city'          => $order->getShippingAddress()->getCity(),
        'weight'        => $order->getWeight(),
        'items'        => $items,
    );
}
```

Comment: first time the it loads all values correctly but second time it fetch first order item quantity also with second order item quantity

Comment: update the code my mistake update the answer

Comment: this code not showing any output for me @QaisarSatti

Comment: @shan this is creating an array

Comment: can u answer me on this question..?
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/310297/get-orders-csv-with-ordered-product-name-and-customers-city @QaisarSatti

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
 foreach ($orderCollection as $order) {
        $orders['orders'][] = array(
            'id'            => $order->getIncrementId(),
            'store'         => 'magento',
            'status'        => $order->getStatus(),
            'name'          => $order->getCustomerName(),
            'email'         => $order->getCustomerEmail(),
            'telephone'     => $order->getShippingAddress()->getTelephone(),
            'street'        => $order->getShippingAddress()->getStreet(),
            'pincode'       => $order->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode(),
            'city'          => $order->getShippingAddress()->getCity(),
            'weight'        => $order->getWeight(),


        );    

     foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
       $orders['orders']['items'][] = array(
            'id'            => $order->getIncrementId(),
            'name'          => $item->getName(),
            'sku'           => $item->getSku(),
            'Price'         => $item->getPrice(),
            'Ordered Qty'   => $item->getQtyOrdered(),


        );

    }
    }
// check array output
echo "<pre>"; print_r($orders);
```

Hope it will helpful to you.