# How can I pull sales orders from a Magento database?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, database, sales-order

I am having issues with my Magento site and need to pull sales orders from my Magento database. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: where you want to pull all the magento orders?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? I just want to pull that info so I can have.

Comment: I mean in which file you want to pull all the orders? e.g Product Page, Category Page

Comment: Oh I am not sure then. My site is having issues so I cannot see anything on admin so was hoping I could get that info. What do you recommend?

Comment: If your admin is not working then what would you do with All Order Information ?

Comment: Well I would need to pull all the sales order to keep records of the sales I have made in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple way to get you started, put this script in the root of the site.

You can pick and choose which fields you want inside the loop. If you are dealing with a large amount of orders this will be slow, and you might want to look into defining a custom walker function (http://inchoo.net/magento/working-with-large-magento-collections/).

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);

Mage::app();

/* tell the browser that we are a csv file */
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=orders.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

/* Set our dates */
$fromDate = '2016-05-20 00:00:00';
$toDate = '2019-01-01 00:00:00';

/* Get the collection. Here we set a date range, and ignore cancelled orders.
   You can filter the collection however you prefer */
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$fromDate, 'to'=>$toDate))
    ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('nin' => array('canceled')));

/* Here you can build an array, print to screen, write to a CSV etc */
echo "Order ID,Customer Name,Order Total".PHP_EOL;
foreach($orders as $o){

    /* lets output the required data in csv format */
    echo $o->getIncrementId().',';
    echo $o->getCustomerName().',';
    echo $o->getBaseGrandTotal();
    echo PHP_EOL;

    /* you can load the order items, if you need them */
    //$items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
}
```

*edit: expanded solution*

Comment: How would it be if I were to want it as a CSV?

Comment: I would probably build an array inside the orders loop, then use fputcsv to write it to a file.

Comment: Do you think you can help me with that? Ouput to the screen is fine.

Comment: What data do you need? e.g. order number, customer name, total value?

Comment: Yeah sounds about right

Comment: OK, try now. The script should create a CSV with the data you mentioned above. If you need any more fields just search on Google how to get them from an order object, and add them in (e.g. "Magento get date from order object")

Comment: One last question is there a way I can also get the sku, item ordered, and quantity ordered?

Comment: I didn't want to bother because I thought it was just going to be a matter of getting the data from the order object but I guess not.

Comment: There is a way, this should cover what you need: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/106845/43657